# Getting auth token automatically using the manifest permissions

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

I try to access Google Drive from an Android application. I use the [getAuthToken](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#getAuthToken%28android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.app.Activity,%20android.accounts.AccountManagerCallback%3Candroid.os.Bundle%3E,%20android.os.Handler%29) method and it's working fine. The user must validate a dialog the first time it will use the application.

However, I wonder whether it would be possible to use the permissions at the installation of the application. For instance, the [Google Drive](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.docs) application can do that. This application can access my Google Drive and it didn't display dialogs to validate permission requests. Looking at the permissions used in the AndroidManifest.xml, one can find:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gm.permission.READ_GMAIL"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.OTHER_SERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.ALL_SERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.writely"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.wise"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
```

I didn't find much information about these permissions , but is it possible to use such permissions to not have to seek validation from the user? Or are these kinds of permission strictly for Google Apps?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that it is not possible to do that. A nice answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13586074/2198638). The best solution seems to display the permission request dialog.